MYSQL - How to find registers with same data in a field, but different data in another field?
I'm trying to identify in my database which users are using other users' "IDs".
MY DB:
ID | NAME | CARDNUMBER | SHOPNUMBER 
1    JO      1234         73839
2    ANDY    9876         79487
3    KARL    5432         87399
4    MIKE    1234         53637

I need to find who is using the same CARDNUMBER with different NAMEs.
Here is JO and MIKE (cardnumber 1234)
I know that "MIKE" is a fixed name - but I don't know how to find the others.
ID | NAME | CARDNUMBER | SHOPNUMBER 
1    JO      1234         73839
2    ANDY    9876         79487
3    KARL    5432         87399
4    MIKE    1234         53637
5    MIKE    5432         93890
6    MIKE    1234         34949
7    GORDON  7389         23339
8    ALEX    8390         28889
9    MIKE    7389         29800

Mike is cloning IDs and I need to find out which IDs.
(I have 50K "FakeIds" created by sellers - but the ID field is required, so these sales are using IDs that could be real customers. When the real customer pulls his data - he will pull the "fake sale" too.) = Mike is "NAME SURNAME" in DB.
I tried to SELECT but I don't know how I can't find these fields
Daniel

It may be a design flaw that allows duplicate entries. In this case, the database design should be reconsidered.

SELECT cardnumber
--   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name SEPARATOR ',') AS names_list
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1;


Please avoid using column numbers in GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it makes queries harder to understand and likely to break if the SELECT list is updated.

Hi @Akina!! First of all, tks for take your time to help me! Your solution was GENIUS! Bright! It solved my problem. Tks a lot!!
Just one thing, would it be possible to filter this result by a name?
Your solution solved - but brings to me some correct rows with abbreviated names - like - John Fox Smith, John F. Smith. To solve this, the fake name is "NAME SURNAME" - I try something like  FROM table where names_List LIKE '%NAME SURNAME%' but I got an error.

@DANIEL like - John Fox Smith, John F. Smith. For to solve this issue you'd normalize your data BEFORE the query. As a palliative you may select and distinct not the whole column name but an expression which normalizes your data. For example it can be CONCAT_WS(' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1)) - it converts both values to 'John Smith'. Also you may add ORDER BY clause into GROUP_CONCAT().

We groupby according to the cardnumber field and select those who use more than one. Then we list their id, name, cardnumber fields in ascending order. You can see the cardnumbers used more than once from here.
SELECT ID, NAME, CARDNUMBER
FROM MY_DB
WHERE CARDNUMBER IN (
    SELECT CARDNUMBER
    FROM MY_DB
    GROUP BY CARDNUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) > 1
) ORDER BY CARDNUMBER ASC;

    


Hi @mustafa, tks a lot for your help!! But this solution brings me back all duplicates CARDNUMBER in DB -- and I need only duplicates CARDNUMBER with different names. Anyway, you give me a good idea to solve the problem. :D

Change COUNT(*) to COUNT(DISTINCT name) to get different names. @DANIEL

@Barmar I edited the answer. I replaced COUNT(*) with COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)

@mustafa - didn't work. I still having duplicate names in the list - now with 8k registers. (without distinct returns 830K)

@Barmar, tks for help me!
